# How can a shared object be statically linked

Tags: linux, gcc, linker, ld-preload

I have a shared object where **file** indicates it is a shared object, and it is used and behaves as a shared object.

```
% file libirc.so
libirc.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=9d54bda46b31ae048aae323dfd809f9ae6c8c55c, not stripped
%
```

But the **ldd** command indicates it is statically linked.

```
% ldd libirc.so
    statically linked
%
```

When I run an executable, ./Solver, that uses this libirc.so it runs as expected.  But when I run the same with LD_PRELOAD="io_functions.so" the run time linker, /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, segfaults just after issuing the error message:

```
./Solver: Relink `./lib/libirc.so' with `/lib64/libc.so.6' for IFUNC symbol `memmove'
```

I can make the run using LD_PRELOAD work by also including libirc.so on the LD_PRELOAD.  I don't have source for libirc.so so I can't figure out much on that end.  I suspect that the troubles are centered on libirc.so being statically linked.  It should not matter what code is in io_functions.so because ld.so doesn't even get to the point of calling the init functions as ld.so is segfaulting while binding symbols.

I have done a bit of investigating using **LD_DEBUG**.  When I run with **LD_PRELOAD=irc/libirc.so** ld.so needs to find memmove for libstdc++
, and uses **memmove [GLIBC_2.2.5]** from /lib64/libc.so.6.  Later ld.so needs to find memmove for libirc.so and also uses memmove from libc.so.6.

```
LD_DEBUG output from successfull run with LD_PRELOAD=irc/libirc.so
3677171:     binding file /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `memmove' [GLIBC_2.2.5]
.
.
.
3677171:     binding file irc/libirc.so [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol 'memmove'
```

When I run the failing job (without **LD_PRELOAD=irc/libirc.so**), ld.so first needs to find memmove for libirc.so and finds it in libc.so.6.  ld.so then prints out the Relink message, followed by a segfault.  **Why does running this way cause the Relink message and segfault, even though its finding memmove for libirc.so in the same place ( libc.so.6 ) as the above successful run?**

```
The last LD_DEBUG line for this process, followed by the print
3676728:     binding file irc/libirc.so [0] to /lib64/libc.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `memmove'
./bin/SMAEqsDirSolverSymmetric: Relink `irc/libirc.so' with `/lib64/libc.so.6' for IFUNC symbol `memmove'
```

Comment: It should not be possible to create such a beast on Linux under glibc. A shred library should depend on ld-linux*.so* at least. There is some kind of magic going on. Perhaps this library acts as its own dynamic loader? No idea...

Comment: My bad, apparently this is very easy to create. Just add `-nostdlib` when linking. Still no idea about the crash.

Comment: My guess would be that libirc.so was manually linked with an old static version of glibc, but don't quote me on that.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing inherently crooked about a DSO that `ldd`
reports as statically linked. In that case `ldd` is just telling
you that the DSO has no dynamic dependencies itself.

Here comes one such:

```
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 13.2.0-4ubuntu3) 13.2.0
```

This compiler emits `PIC` code by default.

```
$ cat hello.c
#include <stdio.h>

void hello(void)
{
    puts("Hello World");
}

$ gcc -shared -o libhello-musl.so hello.c -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-musl/ -l:libc.a
```

The stock [muscl](https://musl.libc.org) static `libc` built for and by my compiler contains `PIC` object files,
so *it* harbours no relocation errors.

```
$ file libhello-musl.so
libhello-musl.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=015152e75131cd274f08fa16447ff926b7c6d85d, not stripped
```

and:

```
$ ldd libhello-musl.so 
statically linked
```

even though I did not attempt to link `-shared -static` (which would fail). `ldd` says that because there is no dynamic section in the shared library:

```
$ readelf --dynamic libhello-musl.so | grep NEEDED; echo Done
Done
```

Because it doesn't need one. Whereas:

```
$ gcc -shared -o libhello-gnu.so hello.c

$ readelf --dynamic libhello-gnu.so | grep NEEDED; echo Done
0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library [libc.so.6]
Done

 
$ ldd libhello-gnu.so 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffc4f5ce000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x000079377ee00000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000079377f104000)
```

`libhello-musl.so` is fit for purpose.

```
$ cat main.c
#include <stdio.h>

extern void hello(void);

int main(void)
{
    hello();
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -o hello main.c -L. -lhello-musl -Wl,-rpath=$(pwd)
$ ./hello
Hello World

$ ltrace -l libhello-musl.so ./hello
hello->hello(1, 0x7ffd219317d8, 0x7ffd219317e8, 0x5c2dd535bda0 <unfinished ...>
libhello-musl.so->puts("Hello World" <unfinished ...>
libhello-musl.so->fputs("Hello World", 0x78c0473fe060 <unfinished ...>
libhello-musl.so->strlen("Hello World")                                                                                                 = 11
libhello-musl.so->fwrite("Hello World", 1, 11, 0x78c0473fe060 <unfinished ...>
libhello-musl.so->memcpy(0x78c0473fe188, "Hello World", 11)                                                                             = 0x78c0473fe188
<... fwrite resumed> )                                                                                                                  = 11
<... fputs resumed> )                                                                                                                   = 0
Hello World
<... puts resumed> )                                                                                                                    = 0
<... hello resumed> )                                                                                                                   = 0
+++ exited (status 0) +++
```

In this light:

> I suspect that the troubles are centered on `libirc.so` being statically linked.

seems to be a misplaced suspicion.

The internet throws up other examples of the same class of

```
Relink `/path/to/libsome.so' with `/path/to/libc.so.6' for IFUNC symbol `symbol'
```

error, in which the observation that `libsome.so` is statically linked does not appear.

These include:

- [Error on runtime: relink /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1' with /usr/glibc-compat/lib/libc.so.6' for IFUNC symbol `memset' #58](https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/issues/58)

in which as it happens the `libsome.so` = `/usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1` transpires to have been
linked against `libc.musl-x86_64.so.1` .

and:

- [Relink '/path/to/libirc.so' with '/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6' for IFUNC symbol 'memmove'](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-C-Compiler/Relink-path-to-libirc-so-with-lib-x86-64-linux-gnu-libc-so-6-for/m-p/1567182#M41708)

which is identical to your error modulo paths.

and:

- [glibc DSO patch causes "Relink /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpixman-1.so.0' with /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6' for IFUNC symbol `sin'" error #209](https://github.com/adamrehn/ue4-docker/issues/209)

which implicates glibc patch:

- [[v8,2/2] elf: Fix slow DSO sorting behavior in dynamic loader (BZ #17645)](https://patchwork.sourceware.org/project/glibc/patch/20211021134122.3141-2-cltang@codesourcery.com/)

committed Oct. 21st 2021.

In this light, like @n. m. could be an AI, I suggest
that the version of `[g]libc` that your `libirc.so` has been statically
linked with is unaligned with the one that your `./Solver` is linked with. The likeliest remedy - as usual? - is to obey the diagnostic: get a new `libirc.so` that you know has been linked
with `libc.so.6` (or a static PIC version of same). If that's difficult just getting the
latest version of `libirc.so` from wherever you got it may be a fix.